# How to get columns with same name from different tables,then how to decrypt them all

Tags: sql, database, mysql-workbench

i want to get same column name of different tables via loop

Comment: Provide more details.

Comment: I assume you are just looking for SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'SOMETHING'

No loop needed

Comment: but i have to encrypt these selected column's values

Comment: but i have to encrypt these selected column's values, please help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM information_schema.columns 
 WHERE column_name = 'SOMETHING'
```

Comment: but i have to encrypt these selected column's values, i think update query is also needed for update

Comment: You need to add more detail on what you are looking for. I have no idea what you want updated.